# Subject is not passing when sending email

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I am sending an email as follows :

```
def sendEmail(serial_number,date, time, latLon):

sender = serial_number+'@sdtr.com'
receivers = ['michael.grobman@station711.com']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receivers
msg['Subject'] = 'Hello!'
msg = MIMEText("""        
    GPS fix

    Lat: %s
    Long: %s
    Time: %s
    Date: %s
    Altitude:
    Velocity: 

    Accuracy
    Horiz: +/- 16 m
    Vert: +/- 32 m

    Please note your reply is limited to 160 Latin characters or approximately 135 for non-Latin characters.

    Sent via bla. The mobile satellite company
    """ % (latLon[0], latLon[1], time, date))


smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('bla', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.login('bla', 'bal')
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
smtpObj.quit()
print("Successfully sent email")
```

issue is that on the receiving side, there is no subject attached to the header,
i have tried few different ways acodring to guide that i have found but still  same result of no subject.

Comment: Please post complete code we can try.

Comment: you will need to chage some of the items to make it work as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have a working email by using only `MIMEText`. Also, I added 2 headers that are quite interesting (Date and Message-ID):

```
from email.utils import make_msgid
from time import asctime


def sendEmail(serial_number, date, time, lat_lon):
    sender = serial_number + '@sdtr.com'
    receivers = ['michael.grobman@station711.com']

    message = """
GPS fix

Lat: %s
Long: %s
Time: %s
Date: %s
Altitude:
Velocity:

Accuracy
Horiz: +/- 16 m
Vert: +/- 32 m

Please note your reply is limited to 160 Latin characters or approximately 135 for non-Latin characters.

Sent via Inmarsat. The mobile satellite company
""" % (lat_lon[0], lat_lon[1], time, date)

    msg = MIMEText(message)
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(receivers)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello!'
    msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()
    msg['Date'] = asctime()

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('...', 587)
    smtpObj.login('...', '...')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
    smtpObj.quit()
    print('Successfully sent email')
```

Comment: I will test this and let you know if it worked for me